# SQL column name search

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio. I have a massive database and I want to search for column names that might be able to help me figure out what I need to join on.

Is there a tool or other method for doing that kind of a search? I have been looking for a way to do a column search but can't find one.

Comment: If there's a problem with my question let me know what it is and I will gladly change it.

Comment: Can't you look at the system catalogue?

Comment: I could, I just didn't know how to do that or that it existed until I asked the question. Also if you haven't already looked at the line that Mike posted it's worth a look.

Comment: Not a SQL Server person, but I do know that they all have their own system catalogues - or stores of metadata if you prefer. You can always use this metadata to find out lots about the system and its setup. Check out Codd's rules [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules), "Rule 4: Active online catalog based on the relational model:

The system must support an online, inline, relational catalog that is accessible to authorized users by means of their regular query language."...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options. Option 1 is to use the system views:

```
select
    t.name
    ,c.column_id
    ,c.name
    ,st.name
from
    sys.tables t
    join sys.columns c on (t.object_id = c.object_id)
    join sys.types st on (c.system_type_id = st.system_type_id)
where
    c.name = ''
```

Option 2 is a free add on from Red Gate Software called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/).

Comment: Newest version of that tool is awesome, big improvement.

Answer (score 1):

I always turn to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. For some reason this is now deprecated; I don't understand why.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'whatever'
```